# playlist in iphone

Tags: iphone

Hi any one help me how to run this live stream link: ex:http://ophanim.net/cast/tunein.php/kplz/playlist.pls in iphone application.

Answer (score 0):

Pull out the URL from the playlist file, then use [Matt Gallagher's Core Audio MP3 streamer](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/revisiting-old-post-streaming-and.html).

Comment: Thank u! But i need to play the play playlist file. please help me!

Comment: Dude, have you even looked at the contents of the playlist.pls file? Here they are: "[playlist]
numberofentries=1
File1=http://174.120.124.178:8017
Title1=STAR 101.5
Length1=-1
version=2"
It's just a URL and metadata. The only thing that's playable is the MP3-over-HTTP stream indicated by the URL.